# Hyperref, tikz node and underline misalignement

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, underline

With a `Tikz` node, there is a shift of the underline line.
I use `lualatex`. See my related question : [pdflatex vs lualatex underline mystery](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414140/pdflatex-vs-lualatex-underline-mystery)

[image]

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,hyperref,tikz}

\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=blue,
    urlbordercolor=blue}

\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W .6pt}}}

\tikzset{RndBox/.style args={#1 and #2}{%
    thick,
    fill=#1,
    inner sep=0pt,
%   outer sep=0pt,
    draw=#2,
    text=#2,
    rounded corners=2pt,
    minimum width=.6cm,
    minimum height=1.25em,
    text depth = 0ex,
    font = \bfseries\sffamily
    },
    RndBox/.default={gray!25 and black}
}

\begin{document}

\href{%
    https://studio.code.org/s/course3/stage/2/puzzle/1}{%
    \smash{Labyrinthe}} un lien

\medskip

\tikz[anchor=base, baseline]
    \node[RndBox,minimum width=20pt] {C} ;
\href{%
    https://studio.code.org/s/course3/stage/2/puzzle/1}{%
    \smash{Labyrinthe}} un lien

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's perhaps just me, but when I compile your snippet, there are no underlines at all. Do you do something special when compiling?

Comment: Interesting, I use `lualatex` and I have the underline. I just tried `pdflatex` and there is no underline as you mentioned it. I'll post a new question.

Comment: Tikz picture needs to be overlayed or raised otherwise it defines the baseline for the underlining

Comment: With overlay option there is an horizontal clash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you know precisely how wide the node is. This suggests

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,hyperref,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=blue,
    urlbordercolor=blue}

\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W .6}}}

\tikzset{RndBox/.style args={#1 and #2}{%
    thick,
    fill=#1,
    inner sep=0pt,
%   outer sep=0pt,
    draw=#2,
    text=#2,
    rounded corners=2pt,
    minimum width=.6cm,
    minimum height=1.25em,
    text depth = 0ex,
    font = \bfseries\sffamily
    },
    RndBox/.default={gray!25 and black}
}

\begin{document}

\href{%
    https://studio.code.org/s/course3/stage/2/puzzle/1}{%
    \smash{Labyrinthe}} un lien

\medskip

\makebox[20pt]{\tikz[anchor=base, baseline,overlay]{
    \node[RndBox,minimum width=20pt] (C) {C} ;}}
\href{%
    https://studio.code.org/s/course3/stage/2/puzzle/1}{%
    \smash{Labyrinthe}} 
    un lien

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I have implements Ulrike's comment on your other question and percusse's proposal.