# pdflatex vs lualatex underline mystery

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, luatex, underline

Using `lualatex`, I have uderlined links :

[image]

Using `pdflatex` they are gone :

[image]

```
\documentclass[french]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,hyperref,tikz}

\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=blue,
    urlbordercolor=blue}

\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W .6pt}}}

\tikzset{RndBox/.style args={#1 and #2}{%
    thick,
    fill=#1,
    inner sep=0pt,
%   outer sep=0pt,
    draw=#2,
    text=#2,
    rounded corners=2pt,
    minimum width=.6cm,
    minimum height=1.25em,
    text depth = 0ex,
    font = \bfseries\sffamily
    },
    RndBox/.default={gray!25 and black}
}

\begin{document}

\href{%
    https://studio.code.org/s/course3/stage/2/puzzle/1}{%
    \smash{Labyrinthe}} un lien

\medskip

\tikz[anchor=base, baseline]
    \node[RndBox,minimum width=20pt] {C} ;
\href{%
    https://studio.code.org/s/course3/stage/2/puzzle/1}{%
    \smash{Labyrinthe}} un lien

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the directive `\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W .6pt}}}`? It seems to do something under LuaLaTeX but not under pdfLaTeX. If I remove this directive, the output of your sample code is the same under both pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: It's the answer I get on this question : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414073/hyperlink-color-problem?noredirect=1#comment1034314_414073

Comment: @Mico, is it underlined in your case? My pdflatex returns the same result with and without that command... but both not underlined...

Comment: I don't use "pt" in my other answer - hyperref warns that this is invalid syntax. `pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W .6}` works fine for me.

Comment: @koleygr - FWIW, I run MacTeX2017, with all the latest updates. I can replicate the OP's observation, i.e., the word is underlined when using LuaLaTeX but not when using pdfLaTeX.

Comment: This works fine for me too. That solves question. Please write an answser. I run texlive 2017 : `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The pdflatex code of hyperref contains some syntax checks. According to this checks your syntax of the pdfborderstyle option is wrong (there should be no `pt` in the value). hyperref warns you in the log (of the pdflatex compilation) that it will ignore the option:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Invalid value `/S/S/W 0.6pt'
(hyperref)                for option `pdfborderstyle'.
(hyperref)                Option setting is ignored on input line 146.
```

The luatex code doesn't have such a check. I don't know if the syntax is really invalid -- perhaps not as it works for luatex. But at least for pdflatex you should change the option to

```
  \AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/S/W 0.6}}}
```